# Creative SDK Image Editor (Web) loads image, waits, then image disappears (no live preview)

Tags: javascript, image, adobe, adobecreativesdk

late night here and at the end of my tether:

Incorporating Creative SDK to edit photos that were uploaded to the server via the previous page in the workflow -

I have tried every one of the parameters on the SDK documentation to find where is the fault in keeping the loaded image active for previewing edits, but in sequence,

> 1. Plugin Initialises (onLoad -> Ok)
> 2. Image loads (onReady -> Ok)
> 3. The Wait icon spins, then
> 4. The image disappears from the edit window
>
> onError() does not pick this up.
>
> Edits are functioning, onSave() fires and I can copy the image
>   (sending the adobe URL via AJaX) to a specified location (file output) on my
>   webspace, BUT, no live preview. Also the image does not update the original as is hard-coded in my script, and it gives an error as though unsaved on closing (isDirty).

My webspace is covered with an SSL certificate, but tried loading the image with relative and absoulte URLs, via http and https - nada.

I am calling version 3 as per the documentation, but people have said try version 4.3.1.29..?

I would like to presevere with this editor for live image editing, but only need it for cropping, adjusting brightness, contrast, rotation etc. and at the moment it is working, but 'blind' - anyone come across this? And how do I fix it...? :)

This is the source, pretty much as specified in the documentation, but with a working AJaX call while 'onSave()':

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://feather.aviary.com/imaging/v3/editor.js"></script>

    <!-- Instantiate Feather -->
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    var featherEditor = new Aviary.Feather({
        apiKey: 'my-key',
        theme: 'dark', // Check out our new 'light' and 'dark' themes!
        tools: 'all',
        displayImageSize: 'true',
        appendTo: '',
        onSave: function(imageID, newURL) {
            var img = document.getElementById("image1");
            img.src = newURL;
            var ph = document.getElementById("new_image_placeholder_div");
            ph.innerHTML = '<img src="'+img.src+'" height="100">';


    var xmlhttp_c;  
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){xmlhttp_c=new XMLHttpRequest();} else {
        xmlhttp_c=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}

            alert("Passing the URL "+newURL+" to the PHP page...");

      xmlhttp_c.open("GET", "feather_save_handler.php?newURL="+encodeURI(newURL), true);

    xmlhttp_c.onreadystatechange=function() { if (xmlhttp_c.readyState==4 && xmlhttp_c.status==200) {

            alert(xmlhttp_c.responseText);      
            alert("Saved!");

            } else { 
                    }
             } 

    xmlhttp_c.send();
    // end save AJaX call..

        },
        onError: function(errorObj) {
            alert(errorObj.args);
        }
    });
    function launchEditor(id, src) {

        featherEditor.launch({
            image: id,
            url: src
        });
        return false;
    }

    </script>
```

The function is kicked off from a form button:

```
<form name="feather_editor" onSubmit="no_submit();">
<input type='image' src='http://images.aviary.com/images/edit-photo.png' value='Edit photo' onclick="return launchEditor('image1', 'http://mywebsitename.com/image_name.jpg');" >
</form>
```

Comment: What have you tried? None of us can help you unless I have something to work with, in particular a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). A great way to explain this is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Also, do check out the [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931) and [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: Code added - all I am expecting is to be able to edit the images with a live preview - all the alerts in the code give the expected returns, except you can't see what you're doing with the image - the preview goes blank!

Comment: It also fails when the editor script is downloaded from the Amazon server recommended for Secure page integration (https://dme0ih8comzn4.cloudfront.net/imaging/v3/editor.js)

 :(

Comment: For your `launchEditor()` helper function, have you verified what the arguments (`id` and `src`) are when they are called? It may be that one or both of those are incorrect.

Comment: For your reference, here is a basic [example repo on GitHub using jQuery](https://github.com/CreativeSDK/web-getting-started-samples/blob/master/image-editor-ui-jquery/index.js).

Comment: Thank you Ash my friend - love your music on SoundCloud btw... 

I set up a test page on my live webspace with one image + button to open the editor - the same thing happens, ie the specified image loads into the editor, the wait graphic spins and then the picture disappears. The code is fully functional and I can open the output file from the server, but disappointed that I can't see what's happening to the image - crazy...

http://www.dafooz.com/feather_test.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this is an issue in your CSS, and should be a fairly simple fix.

## The issue

In `daFooz_main.css`, you have a `canvas` selector that includes:

```
z-index: -1;
```

That's causing the image in the Image Editor to effectively disappear from view since it is a `canvas` element.

## The fix

The fix could be as simple as removing the line above from your CSS.

If you need that line for other areas of your site, try finding a way to be more specific with your selector, perhaps by using classes to target `canvas` elements that you do want to alter the `z-index` of.

Comment: Wow - I did not expect to have to look there!

Problem solved... but I just spent 3 days working on the Lollipop image editor (via code canyon) and debugging the AJaX - the Feather controls are a million times better and more intuitive however. I will stick with that :)

Once again, thank you Ash!